# Expressing y in function of x in a cycloid

Tags: analysis

If we know that the parametric equations of a cycloid is y=r(1-sinθ) ,
x=r(θ-cosθ) is there a way to find the function of the cycloid or in other words somehow find the relationship of y,x ?

Comment: $$ x = r\left(\arcsin\left(1-\frac{y}{r}\right)-\sqrt{1-\left(1-\frac{y}{r}\right)^2}\right) $$ but to write $y$ in terms of $x$ requires the inversion of a trascendental function, that can be done only numerically.

Comment: how did you figure that out?

Comment: If $y=r(1-\sin\theta)$, it is straightforward to write $\theta$ in terms of $y$ and $r$, then plug in such $\theta$ in $x=r(\theta-\cos\theta)$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thank you. I think your comment is already an answer, +1.  Out of additional curiosity - I know of this example: $$y=x^y$$ can be solved for $y$ in terms of $x$ if we allow the use of a special function that itself is defined as an inverse. In that case, it can be done with the Lambert W function ([Apparently this was done by Eisenstein in 1844](https://i.imgur.com/JKi4QnK.png)). Do you think it is possible to do the same for the cycloid; to use some special function to write $y$ in terms of $x$?